# How do I get growl style notification in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

After I added a page to my watchlist on mediawiki.org, it notified me nicely with a little "Growl Style" notification message box and then just hid itself automatically. (As seen below)

[image: Growl Style Notification on Mediawiki.org]

However my own Mediawiki instance (with pretty much all default configuration) doesn't have this feature and I wonder if this can be achieved by some configuration changes or some Javascript/CSS tweaks. See how my Mediawiki instance handles notification below - and it doesn't auto-hide at all:

[image: Plain notification on my Mediawiki instance]

I have enabled both parameters below in LocalSettings.php but I don't think it does the trick:

```
$wgUseAjax = true;
$wgAjaxWatch = true;
```

Please help and I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Nevermind - just found out this is actually a redesign in 1.20 MW - while I'm still with 1.19. https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/17605/6//COMMIT_MSG

Comment: Then you should either add that as an answer to your question and then accept the answer, or delete your question completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a redesign in 1.20 MW - while I'm still with 1.19. gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/17605/6//COMMIT_MSG